# Random Raspbian crash on Raspberry Pi Zero W + RaspiCam

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I have raspbian installed on my RPI Zero W and I wrote simple bash script to make photo on raspicam every 30 sec. (I also have ds1307 to have RTC when RPI is offline)
I add to my crontab:

```
@reboot /home/pi/cam.sh &
```

and I log to file every time my bash script makes photo.
Tonight I started RPI around 00:26 but when I woke up ~9am I realized my RPI crashed, because I can't connect via SSH to it.
So I restarted RPI and I see in /var/log/kern.log this:

```
Dec 24 00:26:55 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

Dec 24 00:50:26 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

Dec 24 00:50:30 raspberrypi kernel: [   19.933260] random: crng init done

Dec 24 09:42:29 raspberrypi kernel: [   20.300288] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
```

(full kern.log here - https://pastebin.com/BbnX2wxW , sorry but I can paste only 30k characters here)

Do you know why my RPI crashes so randomly? this is extreme case of crash after 25 minutes, but sometimes it crashes after 20 or 10 hours, and sometimes after 5 hours, but it crashes every day.
I have second RPI (model B from 2012) without raspicam camera and it has uptime ~6 months, so I'm suprised by crashing here :/